# Parse error: Expected ';', '}' or <eof> at 1:6

Tags: deno

I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/tutorials/hello_world) on how to use Deno. On my attempt to run hello-world.js, terminal started showing me this error:

[image: a terminal entry that says "Deno: parse error: Expected ';', '}' or at 1:6"]

How can I fix it and run the hello-world.js?

I have tried creating hello-world.js file expecting it will resolve the error, but, for some reason, it still returned the same error.
I have also tried reopening the terminal, as well as reinstalling deno into the VSCode. Both attempts resulted in same error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information in your screenshot, you first executed the following command in your shell:

```bash
/Users/maya/.deno/bin/deno ; exit;
```

This will start Deno in [Read-Eval-Print-Loop](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/tools/repl) mode (and then when the REPL exits, the `exit` command will be run in your terminal).

The REPL is an interactive parser, and you attempted to have the runtime parse the input string

```
deno run hello-world.js
```

…which resulted in a parsing (syntax) error — just like what would happen if you tried to do the same thing in any other JavaScript runtime — run the following code snippet to see the syntax error in your browser's JS runtime:

```js
deno run hello-world.js
```

In order to run a module file using Deno, you must execute the `deno run…` command in your actual shell (not in the REPL).

So, instead of running this command…

```bash
/Users/maya/.deno/bin/deno ; exit;
```

…just use this directly:

```bash
/Users/maya/.deno/bin/deno run hello-world.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue!
Turns out, I was opening wrong terminal window all this time. I should have opened regular terminal instead of opening deno file itself. Additionally, there was some small error with locating file, but finding it was resolved by answer from jsejcksn.
Now everything works!